# Prove $f(a)+f(b)=[\frac{2}{(b-a)}] \int_a^b [f(x)+(x-m)f'(x)]dx$.

Tags: real-analysis

Good afternoon!
I'm trying to solve the following problem:

"Show that:

a) given $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$, if $h=\frac{(b-a)}{n}$ and $M(f;n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(a+ih)$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} M(f;n)=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx$;

b) When $n \rightarrow \infty$, then $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (a+ih)= \frac{n-1}{n}\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{b}{n} \rightarrow \frac{a+b}{2}$;

c) Use (a) and (b) to prove that, given $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$, whose derivative is Riemann integrable, and $m=\frac{a+b}{2}$, then $f(a)+f(b)=[\frac{2}{(b-a)}] \int_a^b [f(x)+(x-m)f'(x)]dx$.

My solution:

a) Consider a partition $P=\{t_1,...,t_n\}$ of [a,b], such that  $t_1=a+h, t_2=a+2h,...,t_n=a+nh$, with $h=\frac{b-a}{n}$. The Riemann sum $\sum(f;P*)$ of the function $f$ over the partition $P$ may be written as $\sum(f;P*)= \sum_{i=1}^n f(a+ih)(t_i-t_{i-1})=\sum_{i=1}^n f(a+ih)h=\sum_{i=1}^n f(a+ih) \frac{b-a}{n}$. Then, $\int_a^b f(x)dx= \lim_{|P|\rightarrow 0} \sum(f;P*)= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f(a+ih)\frac{b-a}{n}$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^nf(a+ih)=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx$.

b) $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (a+ih)=\frac{a+h+a+2h+...+a+nh}{n}=\frac{na+h(1+2+...+n)}{n}=\frac{na+nh+[h(1+2+...+(n-1)]}{n}=a+\frac{b-a}{n}+\frac{b-a}{2}\frac{n-1}{n}=a+\frac{b-a}{n}+\frac{(b-a)(n-1)}{2n}+\frac{2a(n-1)}{2n}-\frac{2a(n-1)}{2n}$=$a+\frac{b-a}{n}-\frac{a(n-1)}{n}+\frac{(b+a)(n-1)}{2n}=\frac{b}{n}+\frac{(b+a)}{2}\frac{(n-1)}{n}$.

Evidently, $\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{b}{n} \rightarrow \frac{a+b}{2}$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$

Please, help me to find a solution for item (c).

Comment: The first assertion is only true if the Riemann integral is known to exists, what is your assumption on f?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this:

what you need to do is to write the right hand side as the limit of

$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n f(a+ih) +\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\bigg(a+ih-\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(a+ih)\bigg)\bigg(\dfrac{f(a+ih)-f(a+(i-1)h)}{h}\bigg)$

I think if you sort this out carefully, this gives the left hand side. Notes a lot of the cross terms cancels on the right when you expand the brackets.

I cannot guarantee this is completely correct, but I think this is pretty close.